# Nested looping through data validation cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with 2 cells that are both using data validation lists (cell B3 and B4 in the below). The list item chosen in each cell is used in a formula that outputs 2 results (one in C21 and the other in C22). What I am trying to do is present all iterations and their result in C21 and C22. How I have approached this is by looping through all data validation items in B4 and for each item in B4, loop through all options in B3.

There are 8 different options in B3 and 4 different options in B4. Using Offset, I am presenting the outputs of this in a separate tab called "Sensitivity Output" which I would expect to be a table 8 columns wide and 16 rows deep.

In addition to this, I am getting an error of "Object required" on the line "Set divRange = Evaluate(divCell.Validation.Formula1)"

Code below as presented which partially works but is not presenting the desired result at the moment.

I am new to VBA but as far as I understand this it should be working?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Sub Sensitivty()
'
' Sensitivty Macro
'
    Dim ebitCell As Range
    Dim ebitRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set ebitCell = Sheets("Assumptions Input").Range("B3")
    Set ebitRange = Evaluate(ebitCell.Validation.Formula1)
    
    Dim divCell As Range
    Dim divRange As Range
    Dim d As Range
    
    Set divCell = Sheets("Assumptions Input").Range("B4")
    Set divRange = Evaluate(divCell.Validation.Formula1)
    
    'Looping through items in B4
     For Each d In divRange
      divCell.Value = d.Value
     
     'For each item in B4, loop through each of the items in B3
            For Each c In ebitRange
                   
                    ebitCell.Value = c.Value
                    Worksheets("Assumptions Input").Activate
                    Range("C21:C22").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Worksheets("Sensitivity Output").Activate
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                     :=False, Transpose:=False
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            Next c
          
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, -8).Select
            
        Next d
    
    Set ebitCell = Nothing
    Set ebitRange = Nothing
    Set divCell = Nothing
    Set divRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use activate or select: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: What does `Evaluate(divCell.Validation.Formula1)` return?

Comment: @SJR it should give the full list of items included in the data validation in the cell specified

Comment: Yes but what does it actually return?

Comment: It returns the follow: "60% Margin,33% Margin,25.79% Margin,Breakeven". Not sure how to check that on the actual code, but that is from the data validation rule on B4

Comment: `Set divRange` is expecting a range, not a string.

Comment: What is the validation formula you're using?

Comment: There isn't a validation formula? Sorry, this is where I am new and thought that was just part of syntax

Comment: Ok so how are you populating the DV list? Perhaps you can post an [mcve].

Comment: `Dim arr; arr = Split(divCell.Validation.Formula1, ",")` then loop over the array `arr`.  Your posted code is designed for a validation list which uses a linked range, not one where you've manually entered the items as a list directly in the DV dialog.

Comment: @TimWilliams I changed this to a linked range (with 1 small correction to the code posted) and works perfectly. Answered the question too as it was obvious this is the only issue. Thanks for the pointer and damn good spot!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this is actually a working piece of code (slight adjustment to original to correct a small error made). The issue I faced was that the code was built to work off data validation used a linked range rather than a list (which I had in place at D4). This works as expected when using a linked range for both B3 and B4 in the example given